# Integrate MathJax into SystemJS build

Tags: angular, build, systemjs, mathjax

I use `SystemJS` to build an `Angular 2` application and I'd like to start using `MathJax` in a component. I installed with:

```
npm install --save-dev mathjax
npm install --save @types/mathjax
```

MathJax is now installed in `/node_modules/mathjax`.  When my component does `import "mathjax"`, the file `/node_modules/mathjax/MathJax.js` is loaded.  So far so good.

Problem is that this file then tries to load other files using paths relative to the project root instead of the MathJax install directory.

For instance, `MathJax.js` tries to load

```
/extensions/MathMenu.js  404 Not found
/extensions/MathZoom.js  404 Not found
```

The correct paths are

```
/node_modules/mathjax/extensions/MathMenu.js
/node_modules/mathjax/extensions/MathZoom.js
```

A quick look inside the source files show that the URLs are referred to this way:

```
[MathJax]/extensions/MathMenu.js
```

Any idea where I should look to fix this? I know I shouldn't alter the `MathJax.js` file itself since any change will be overwritten after an update. It also doesn't make sense to use `htaccess` or other server-side redirects.

I'm aware that I can load a working MathJax bundle by using the CDN:

```
<script src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=AM_SVG"></script>
```

However I'm trying to learn how to integrate the library into my build setup.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put, you cannot integrate MathJax like this (at this time).

MathJax inludes a custom dynamic module loader designed to work all the way down to IE6; unsurprisingly, it does not work with contemporary build tools.

But very likely you also **don't want** to integrate MathJax in its entirety because that comes in at a couple of dozen megabytes (compressed). Now, in practice, you don't need all components, typically developers need 1 input + 1 output + 1 set of fonts which comes down to around ~500-600KB (compressed).

If that's a feasible pay load, then you could look into building a customized single-file build (such as [this one](https://github.com/pkra/MathJax-single-file)) which you should be able to integrate.

For what it's worth, compatibility with contemporary build tools is a deliverable for MathJax v3.0 next year.

*Full disclosure: I'm part of the MathJax team.*

Comment: Hi, any update on this now it's been 12+months? Can you guide me/us as to the best course of action to integrate MAthJax with a SystemJs application. The current npm version is still 2.*. If 3.0 isn't ready yet can you advise of likely timeframes? Many thanks! :-)

Comment: @john [MathJax v3](https://github.com/mathjax/mathjax-v3/) is in beta now and should integrate easily.

Comment: That's awesome thanks for the update! Do you have a feel for when it'd be out of beta? Roughly.