# Make Angular 2 component download and run a script

Tags: javascript, angular, mathjax

I am trying to use [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/#modal-livedemo) to display equations in my `Angular 2` app. Only a small bit of my app actually needs this functionality, so I don't want all users to have to download the 3-400kb needed.

My initial thought was to `import "mathjax"` within my component, so that the library will be loaded only when the component is created. However, I learned [from my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40989264/integrate-mathjax-into-systemjs-build) that MathJax doesn't play well with others because it uses its own custom module loader.

My current setup loads the `script` from my `index.html` but that means *everyone* will download it when only a small percentage of users need this component

```
<script src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=AM_SVG"></script>
```

Is there a clean way in `Angular 2` to have my component download a script within the `ngOnInit()` hook and execute a callback once it's in the DOM?  Something such as (pseudo-code):

```
ngOnInit(){
    //download script, add to DOM      
    fetch('https://...MathJax.js').then(addToDom).then(this.onMathJaxLoaded);
}
onMathJaxLoaded(){
  // Run math renderer
  MathJax.Hub.Queue("Typeset",...);
}
```

Comment: Might be a option to inject a `<script>` tag into your DOM.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230886/trying-to-fire-onload-event-on-script-tag

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Thanks for the note

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not tried it, but I think this might be possible:

```
ngOnInit(){
    //download script, add to DOM      
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    document.body.appendChild(script)
    script.onload = this.onMathJaxLoaded.bind(this);
    script.src = 'https://...MathJax.js';
}
onMathJaxLoaded(){
  // Run math renderer
  MathJax.Hub.Queue("Typeset",...);
}
```

Here is a fiddle, which contains a example of how it would work in plain JavaScript; https://jsfiddle.net/5qu5h7bc/

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. It works. I need to refine it a bit because there is a lot of redundancy: in the `Angular 2` app, there can be many instances of this component (each component holds a user comment) and I'm seeing 11 scripts loaded and 11 tags added when the page has 11 comments. Ideally, the script tag would be added just once, though `onMathJaxLoaded` must be run 11 times, once to render each comment.

Comment: Cool, please accept if works.. One way to ensure that the tag is only added once, is to set a global variable like `isMathJaxLoaded` and if it is `true`, then just call `this.onMathJaxLoaded` otherwise append the `script`-tag

Comment: Your code inspired me to my posted solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Building on @TryingToImprove's solution, I decided to add a `ScriptLoaderService` to my app with a `load()` function that fetches a remote script and notifies the caller (using an [RxJS Observable](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-introduction-to-reactive-extensions-rxjs-a86a7430a61f)) when it's done.

Here is how to use it:

```
this.scriptLoaderService.load('https://...js').subscribe(
    ()=>console.log('script has loaded');
);
```

Here is the service:

```
/**
 * A directory of scripts that have been or are being loaded
 */
private scripts = new Map<string,Observable<boolean>|boolean>();

/**
 * Downloads script; returns Observable that emits TRUE once "load" event fires
 */
public load(src:string):Observable<boolean>{        
    if(this.scripts.has(src)){
        // If script has already been fully loaded.
        if(this.scripts.get(src)===true) return Observable.of(true);

        // Else if download is already underway but load event hasn't fired yet
        else return this.scripts.get(src);
    }

    //Add a script tag to the DOM
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    // upon subscription, listen for the load event. Once it arrives, emit TRUE
    let obs:Observable<boolean> = Observable.fromEvent(script,'load')
        // Map should hold TRUE once script is loaded
        .do(()=> this.scripts.set(src,true))
        .take(1).map(e=>true);

    // set the src attribute (will cause browser to download)
    script.src = src;

    //add observable to the scripts Map
    this.scripts.set(src,obs);

    return obs;
}
```

Tested on `Firefox 51`